# Retain/Release with stringByReplacingCharactersInRange Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I was observing my memory footprint in Instruments and noticed a huge spike when I call the method below. The method performs a great deal of string manipulations and I'm wondering if I need to be retaining/releases NSStrings. If anyone sees anyway to improve this method please let me know.

```
-(void)findWords:(NSString *)query {
     //Removes Characters that aren't approved by me
     NSString *usersLetters = [query substringWithRange:allLetters];
     NSString *userLettersBackup = [query substringWithRange:allLetters];

     //Loop over all words in a NSDictionary
     for(NSString *word in wordSection)
     {
        int wordLength = [word length];

        //Loop Over each char in the word
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
        {
          char current = [word characterAtIndex:i];

           //Loop Over each char in the usersletters 
           for (int indexUser = 0; indexUser <[usersLetters length]; indexUser++)
           {
             char compare = [usersLetters characterAtIndex:indexUser];
             if(current == compare){
                //Is this losing reference to the other userLetters?
                //and retaining the previous value?
                usersLetters = [usersLetters stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(indexUser, 1) withString:@"*"];
             } 
           }
        }
        //Reset the UserLetters for looking at the next word
        usersLetters = userLettersBackup;
      }
 }
```

Comment: What's this method supposed to be doing?

Comment: It just counts how many letters in query are matched in the word. I left out the counting part.

Comment: Any idea how many times that inner `usersLetters` assignment is being executed in general?  Since you're creating strings and tossing them into the auto-release pool none of them will actually be released until some time after this method ends.

Comment: It's executed almost all the time and that seems to be driving up my memory footprint and has caused my app to crash. Is there a better way to handle this before the pool drains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spike is probably coming from the large amount of autoreleased objects that are getting created.  In terms of memory management, I don't see anything that's immediately wrong.

You could `alloc`/`init` an `NSAutoreleasePool` at the beginning of the method and `drain` it at the end.

Comment: or indeed drain after every X words.